# Cocos2dx using c++ and lua

Tags: c++, lua, cocos2d-x-3.0

I supposed to using the cocos2dx + C++ to do the most job in application, and use lua to some ui part job.
And here is a question:
In bool `AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching()`: I using this codes to config the design screen size

```
glview->setDesignResolutionSize(designResolutionSize.width, designResolutionSize.height, ResolutionPolicy::NO_BORDER);
```

But what will happen if I change the config in config.lua.

```lua
CONFIG_SCREEN_ORIENTATION = "landscape"
-- design resolution
CONFIG_SCREEN_WIDTH  = 960
CONFIG_SCREEN_HEIGHT = 640
-- auto scale mode
CONFIG_SCREEN_AUTOSCALE = "FIXED_HEIGHT"
```

Is there any solution can resolve the config issue if I am using c++ and lua?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after some test, I found a way to resolve it.
The c++ codes only work in the c++ enviroment, and the lua config only works in the lua enviroment, so we have to let the properties of them be same.